# psycopg2.OperationalError FATAL: role "ubuntu" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, airflow

I'm on windows and i installed ubuntu terminal, this is what i'm doing:
https://medium.com/@ryanroline/installing-apache-airflow-on-windows-10-5247aa1249ef

When i run `airflow initdb` i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    ...
  File "/home/lucas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
```

But i did create profile and assign the correct privileges:

```
CREATE ROLE ubuntu;
CREATE DATABASE airflow;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on database airflow to ubuntu;
ALTER ROLE ubuntu SUPERUSER;
ALTER ROLE ubuntu CREATEDB; 
ALTER ROLE ubuntu LOGIN;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to ubuntu;
```

I don't know why it keeps getting this error.

Comment: We are going to need to see what is in:```airflow.cfg``` in particular what ```sql_alchemy_conn``` is set to.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it, in the postgres configuration i have port 5433 and in airflow configuration i had 5432.

Comment: Same here, I wanted to login to one PostgreSQL database running on (default) port 5432 with credentials I had set up on another instance on port 5433...